# Clone/Mirror SVN repos

Tags: svn, repository, clone

I need to clone a SVN repo which is there on a remote site to my server. I have access to the SVN repo. But when I clone I want the entire history of the repo to be intact. What are the possible ways of doing this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

dump of your existing repo
`svnadmin dump D:\Repositories\myexistsingproject > myexistsingproject.dump`

create a new repo
`svnadmin create D:\Repositories\mynewproject`

load the back up of the existing repo
`svnadmin load D:\Repositories\mynewproject < myexistsingproject.dump`

Comment: When I do something like `svnadmin dump https://SERVER+PATH/trunk`, it throws an error that is an URL when it should be a path. What am I missing ? I access the repo through a URL

Comment: I got what I wanted at http://pogopixels.com/blog/dumping-a-svn-repository-from-a-remote-url/. I think your solution works for local repos and not for remote repos

Comment: Can use [svnrdump](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svnrdump.html) for remote repositories.